# Fragment created multiple times within RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button

I have an activity with a RadioGroup that has two RadioButtons. The RadioButtons behave like tabs and should create two different fragments, depending on which of the buttons has been clicked. The problem is that the fragments' onCreateView methods are called twice and I can't figure out why.

This is my Activity:

```
public class MyActivity {

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private FrameLayout frame;
private RadioButton radio1;
private RadioButton radio2;

private RadioOneFragment radio1Fragment;
private RadioTwoFragment radio2Fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

    radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radio1:
                    radio1Fragment = new RadioOneFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.radio_frg_container, radio1Fragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2:
                    radio2Fragment = new RadioTwoFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.radio_frg_container, radio2Fragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        radioGroup.check(R.id.radio2);
    } else {
        radioGroup.check(R.id.radio1);
    }
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this behavior caused because I'm checking the radiobuttons within my code?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer here: [RadioGroup calls onCheckChanged() three times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263778/radiogroup-calls-oncheckchanged-three-times)

Instead of using `radioGroup.check(R.id.radio1)` you should simply use `radio1.setChecked(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try one Fragment object

```
private RadioOneFragment radio1Fragment;
private RadioTwoFragment radio2Fragment;
```

instace of

```
private RadioTwoFragment radioFragment;
```

and

```
switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radio1:
                    radioFragment = new RadioOneFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.radio_frg_container, radioFragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2:
                    radioFragment = new RadioTwoFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.radio_frg_container, radioFragment)
                            .commit();
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem