# RadioGroup.check() make OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged called twice

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have some `RadioButtons` in a `RadioGroup`， and I set `OnCheckedChangeListener` to the `RadioGroup` like this:

```
public class RadioGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.radio_a)
    RadioButton radioA;
    @Bind(R.id.radio_b)
    RadioButton radioB;
    @Bind(R.id.radio_c)
    RadioButton radioC;
    @Bind(R.id.radio_group)
    RadioGroup radioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_group);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Log.i("radio", "onCheckedChanged checkId = "+checkedId);
            }
        });

        radioGroup.check(radioC.getId());
    }
}
```

My question is that, when this `Activity` start, I think I can get the Log only once, but I got twice:

```
07-19 12:26:30.765 I/radio: onCheckedChanged checkId = 2131493018
07-19 12:26:30.765 I/radio: onCheckedChanged checkId = 2131493018
```

`2131493018` is the id of the `radioC`. But when I touch the screen to check a radioButton, `onCheckedChanged` called once.

Anyone can help with this ? thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10264033/3117966) out

Comment: You could use radioC.setChecked(true);

Comment: @Nisarg thank u, your comment answered all my questions. And I will give my question a duplicate tag.

Comment: @L.Swifter Yes right and welcome :)